# Configuration qualifers - Multiple screen size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support, android-screen

I'm creating an application for smartphone tablet and televison.
I'm creating my different displays, but I can not differentiate the tablet from the television. 
I read https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

I have tried many things, large,xlarge sw720dp, W1024dp.. but nothings works. I work with the emulator.

AndroidTv 1080p  API 25, Résolution 1920*1080:xhdpi

Nexus 5 API 24  Résolution 1080*1920:xxhdpi

Nexus 7  1200*1920 xhdpi

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Use `-television` to distinguish a television from a mobile device with respect to resources. See [the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you want is here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

The important parts of this page are **Table 2** (configuration qualifier names) and the section titled **How Android Finds the Best-matching Resource**.

Reading these, it is clear that you will use the *Smallest width* qualifier to differentiate between phone and tablet devices, and the *UI mode* to differentiate between televisions and non-televisions. This directory structure should work:

```
res/
    layout/
        layout.xml (default (i.e. phones))
    layout-sw600dp/
        layout.xml (non-televisions 600dp or wider (i.e. tablets))
    layout-sw600dp-television/
        layout.xml (televisions 600dp or wider)
```

Because the *Smallest width* qualifier has a higher precedence than the *UI mode* qualifier, if you tried to just use `layout-television` you would find that your TV still used the `-sw600dp` layout.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but unfortunately the TV opens layout.xml (default) .

Comment: I don't know if it plays, but when I am in the layout "television" I can't choose android tv as device in design. 
i mean when i  choose TV, this redirect me on activity_main (default) and change the device, and so the activity_main(television) keep Nexus4.   
Nevertheless I have the nexus 7 on the tablet design and the nexus 5 on the default but I can not put the tv on Televesion

Comment: Finally, i used : 
  res/
        layout/
            layout.xml (default (i.e. phones))
        layout-sw600dp/
            layout.xml (non-televisions 600dp or wider (i.e. tablets))
        layout-land-television-notouch/
            layout.xml (televisions)


                               And it works, I don't know why I had the problem with my previous review but good, it works now so thank you